# How to fix 'Import Error: No module named' in python2.7

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I got Import Error when I put a module into existed project.
The folder structure is follow:

```
model
  /new_sub_model
     __init__.py
     new_file.py
  /sub_model
     __init__.py
     file.py
  __init__.py
  file_to_import.py
```

*new_sub_model* and the file under it written by me, and sub_model is existed before, both new_file.py and file.py import file_to_import.py, and it works in file.py but not in new_file.py, got error like title shows. every file has the **init**.py.

the import statements listed below

```py
    from model.file_to_import import function
the error traceback lists below

        from model.file_to_import.py import function
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
        result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
    ImportError: No module named file_to_import
```

I don`t know what the problem is and how to fix it. Glad to have your answer.

**Edited:** I solved this problem by using statement

```py
    from..file_to_import import function
```

this solve my problem, but I dont know why.

Comment: could you copy your import statements?

Comment: please provide a full traceback and at least the relevant code.

Comment: @EliranTurgeman I just edit the question and add the import statements. Thank You!

Comment: On which file this import statement is written?

Comment: @EliranTurgeman In new_file. The new_sub_model is added to the project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `__init__.py` in your model directory hence it cannot be used as a module. In  the working file, there must be something that appends the folder to the path where Python looks for the modules. Without any more specific structure and code that is my best guess.

Comment: It has the __init__file in project, Sorry for not add it in the problem, I have edited the problem. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Python uses the current directory for import statements, so if you are trying to import something from and 'upper' directory it won't find it.
Simply use these lines before the import statement:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '../')
```

And change the import statement to `from file_to_import import function`

Comment: But how the statements in sub_model.fle.py works? the import statements in both new_file.py and file.py are the same. And in file.py without the code you post. Thank you